# amcharts automatic scaling is wrong when there is only one bar

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

As the title suggests, when there is only one bar (can happen with more, but I prefer to focus on that problem), the bar is extremely small.
Here's my plotting code (the relevant part in my opinion):

```
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
  categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "uri";
  categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
  categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 10;
  categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.horizontalCenter = "right";
  categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.verticalCenter = "middle";
  categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.rotation = 315;
  categoryAxis.tooltip.disabled = true; 
  categoryAxis.renderer.minHeight = 110;

  categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add
  ("textOutput", function(text) {return text.substring(text.lastIndexOf("/")+1);});

  var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
  valueAxis.renderer.minWidth = 50;
  valueAxis.logarithmic = true;
  valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
```

[This happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmyeG.png) when a category with a yAxis value that is close to 10, 100, 1000 and so on.

I would like the bar to be higher. What do I need to do?

Comment: The scaling isn't wrong - you're using a logarithmic axis, which is working as designed. logarithmic is meant for cases where you need to represent a large range of values when you have several data points or more and it uses the log function to calculate the scale; the chart scales the size of the bar with respect to the axis' value range, which can be skewed to a much larger range when logarithmic is enabled. Consider disabling it if it's not meant for your use case or set your own value axis max if you must have it enabled.

Comment: Thing is, I need the logarithmic view for any other case. 
What do you mean by "set your own value axis max"? I want it to be dynamic - not a hard coded maximum value.

Comment: By setting your own max, I meant hard coding it. Since that's not an option, consider adding logic to determine when to enable logarithmic or not, i.e. if your data set has few values, set it to false and then enable it when your data set grows beyond that threshold.